# MySQL - Should I use a stored procedure or something else?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

This is my first question on stackoverflow. I can usually find the answer to my questions by searching but this time I haven't had such luck.

I have several databases in MySQL. They are used by several ruby on rails applications. These applications are not all the same version. That is the same version of our custom software not of rails etc. So there are some differences to core tables and columns within our app.

I want to be able to change one column of one row based on if the column name is lets say foo or bar for all the databases. So foo would be the column name to store the information of an earlier version and bar is the updated column name. I want to change the information for id 1 depending on if the column name is foo or bar. For example:

```
IF database.table.foo EXISTS
  THEN UPDATE database.table.foo WHERE id='1' to blahblah
ELSE IF database.table.bar EXISTS
  THEN UPDATE database.table.bar WHERE id='1' to blahblah
ELSE
  Skip database
END
```

I have limited experience with MySQL. Right now I am running a BASH script to build a .sql file that is executed on the MySQL server based on the version of our software. This has several holes in it and as our application changes these disparities will become more of a hassle.

So in this situation would a stored procedure be the best option or is there something else I am completely missing?

Thank you for you help! :-)

Comment: How about rake task insted?

Comment: @BroiSatse I would like to change this without having to update each instance of our application. There are hundreds and would take a lot of time. Where as if I just change the one column this would take a lot less time and resources.